# Storing object with params with values in a database and fetch them

Tags: database, optimization

We are developing an ad-publishing site similar to craigslist. There we have advertisement, category and its params. The params are attached to categories. And the params has values. And those values depend on other values. For ex., when I choose param "BMW" there have to appear BMW models like "X6, X5, M3" etc.

We tried to solve in it this way.

We have tables

```
Params(id, category_id, parent_id, name)
ParamValues(id, param_id, is_string, int_value, string_value)
Ads(id,category_id) and Ads_paramvalues_join(ad_id, param_value_id).
```

We added string_value and int_value, because when the user will make search, he may choose the int range or constant value from list.

The problem is - that the `join table(Ads_paramvalues_join)` will become very big, because it will contain mapping from each parameter value. Seems it may cause performance issue.

Here we are using Hibernate 3, Spring 3 MVC.

We'd like to know is there any other kind of best practices and patterns to solve such problem in such cases.

Comment: This structure is a species of what is known as as "Entity-Attribute-Value" (EAV) schema. The use of EAV schemas is widely considered an antipattern. There's a good writeup of it in the book [SQL Antipatterns](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557) - there are slides of it on the web you should be able to google up. As Luc suggests, you should just give each type its own table.

Answer (score 2):

You should seperate the issue at first when running a relational database as I expect you to do so:

In basic you have seperate real life object with their parameters:
Car: Engine, colour, seats, doors, etc.
Bike: Frame size, wheel size, colour, lightening etc.

They are just different, based on normalization it would be strange to group them all into one table. A car just isn't a bike.

Now you have the problem that you see them as some sort of general object: Advertisement.

That's where your problems starts, in fact: You are building a database in a database. And that's not a well known good practice.

What would make sense, some options:

1. Just give an object it's own tabel, so a table cars, a table bikes etc.
2. Add all properties of your objects into one table (nullable). So: object_type(bike/car), Engine, colour, seats, doors, framesize, wheel size, lightening etc etc.
3. Think about some many-to-many design like tags, that's kinda the way you are going now.
4. Think about a different way of storing your data, RDBMS are right many time but for this kind of flexible storage like key-value storage databases might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have about 100s of objects. Besides cars, i have dresses, kitchen stuff, tvs, radios, cups, even spoons. So you say that I have to make separate tables to each of them?! Doesn't it take a lot of time? Is that the good practice?

Comment: That would be stated just taking a look at the objects. But is has also disadvantages, for example: How many advertisements do we in total? You would need a call to lots of tables. Though it looks doable. Sure when you use and external search index like Solr.

I would try not to put this in a normal RDBMS if you have a serious business case with a big database. Try to take a look at MongoDB for example. This kind of databases are more easy to scale and allow more flexibility in the attributes you assign to a product. Maybe relevant: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/mongodb-for-ecommerce